# Add Leaderboard to iOS game

Tags: ios, game-center, sprite-kit

I just implemented Game Center into my Sprite Kit game, and now I need to create a leaderboard. It looks like I need to add my game to iTunes Connect in order to create a leaderboard, but I'm nowhere close to submitting my game to the app store. Do I have to do this and set a availability date for my app in order to create a leaderboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, you don't have to have to submit the app, **but** you *must* add the app and then go to the 'manage game center' tab and create a leader board. The availability date **won't** really come into play until you **submit** the app.

Comment: So I can change the availability date later?